# Is discussing Hentai allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, questions, asking-questions

I just had to ask but are discussions on hentai topics allowed here? It is something that people might end up doing here, so I just wanted someone to clear the air.

Comment: Would this include *ecchi* material as well? As I recall, *ecchi* tends to be even more fetishistic and, well, weird.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would imagine if anything, it would have the same rules as the failed [Sexuality.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality)

We have a [similar](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/are-adult-movies-as-far-as-industry-actors-etc-are-concerned-on-topic) rule on Movies.SE about Adult-Movies that everything should be kept in a scientific sense.

Comment: +1: I think this makes perfect sense as a general guideline.  I suspect most people will probably intuit it...and those that don't will have it kindly explained to them.

Comment: Is this an encouragement to discuss jiggle physics? :-p

Comment: @RachelKeslensky I don't think you'd find much argument against.  WE NEED FORMULAS PEOPLE

Comment: I agree with this. Use *mature* language (nothing that would elicit Beavis-and-Butthead type laughter) and be a grown-up about it. We're all adults here, we can be good about this.

Comment: @user74: SE sites are for 13+ we are NOT "all adults" here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it should be allowed.  It's anime.  That said, it's probably also the case that it should be policed pretty tightly...but then, I guess everything is like that.  I don't imagine too many questions will come up about it, but I don't see any reason to police them any differently than any other question.  If it's a reasonable question, vote it up and try to answer it.  If not, vote it down.  If it's offensive, flag it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by offensive? Offensive to whom? All questions on here could be considered offensive if one person finds it offensive.

Comment: @KenLi : Right.  Which is why everyone can flag.  There is no one definition for offensive...so the SE admins built in the flagging mechanism to allow people to come to a generalized consensus.  I'm saying the mechanism for determining "offensiveness" is already in place, and probably better than we could define by trying to do so in a catch-all question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, questions regarding the best material to wank off to should be 100% not allowed.  However, discussions regarding some of the other aspects of hentai should be fine.  Some of the highest animation qualities I've ever seen have been in hentai works, and the story-lines of some are surprisingly well thought out.

Of course, this is assuming you're talking about honest-to-god hentai, and not just simple ecchi.  Anime like Gakuen Mokushiroku or Highschool DxD are not hentai.  They're ecchi.  they should be 100% fine here.

Comment: `would say, questions regarding the best material to wank off to should be 100% not allowed`   That type of question would fall under "not constructive", and would be closed as such.

Comment: @Wipqozn hence, why i said it should be not allowed.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that subject matter had nothing to do with why that specific question would be closed :P